# How to reduce number of joins?

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive

I have to left join two tables where from right table I need some columns On a join condition of three columns, and some columns on join condition of two similar but one different column   (again 3 columns) and some columns on join condition of one column (which is one of the non-matching columns in previous joins).

Let me explain by example

Table A has columns a1, a2, a3, a4, a5
Table B has columns b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7

Now I need

- a1,
- a2,
- a3,a4,
- b1 when a2=b2, a3=b3, a4=b4,
- b6 when a2=b5, a3=b3, a4=b4,
- b7 when a2=b2

Now How can I achieve this without joining the tables multiple times, Or as less times as possible. With CASE WHEN THEN structure or anything else. The queries are for Hive but most of sql features are supported. Hive has different optimization techniques but sql guys are welcome.

Thanks in advance for your effort.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help people understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `hive` supports `conditional aggregation`.  If I'm understanding your question correctly, you should be able to use that with a `cross join`:

```
select a1, a2, a3, a4, 
       max(case when a2 = b2 and a3 = b3 and a4 = b4 then b1 end) b1,
       max(case when a2 = b5 and a3 = b3 and a4 = b4 then b6 end) b6,
       max(case when a2 = b2 then b7 end) b7
from a cross join b 
group by a1, a2, a3, a4
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replaying, I need to do a left join, would it be same as cross join here? And I'm failing to see why I need to use max function?

Comment: @HimanshuMehra -- which table do you need to use in the `outer join`?  This should return all results from `a` with those matching values in `b`.  `max` is used with `conditional aggregation`, basically table pivoting (an alternative to multiple joins).

Comment: @sgedds I'm sorry I'm new in sql and hive so I'm still failing to understand how and why table is being pivoted. max function definition is 'Returns the maximum value of the column in the group.' And i'm guessing this means if you pass it multiple column it will return the one which has higher value for the particular record. Am I right on that? Thanks for helping out.
EDIT : But max function seems to take only one value

Comment: @HimanshuMehra -- have you tried it?  using `max` with `case` is different than using `max` alone.  you are correct, `max` returns the maximum value in that group.  but in this case, using `case` changes the group to only the potential values in the when statement. lots of examples on conditional aggregation out there.  common practice to convert multiple rows into columns...

Comment: @sgedds Thanks,This works. I got it how, But why . . why are we converting rows to columns? Please refer some link if you can. it will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do multiple joins:

```
select a.a1, a.a2, a.a3, a.a4, b1.b1, b2.b6, and b3.b7
from a join
     b b1
     on a.a2 = b1.b2 and a.a3 = b1.b3 and a.a4 = b1.b4 join
     b b2
     on a.a2 = b2.b5 and a.a3 = b2.b3 and a.a4 = b2.b4 join
     b b3
     on a.a2 = b.b2;
```

You may need `left join` if some conditions do not match.

Comment: But OP specifically says: `Now How can I achieve this without joining the tables multiple times`.  I agree this would work though.

Comment: @sgeddes . . . I think this is the best solution to the problem the OP describes, especially given the environment s/he is working in.

Comment: Fair enough, can't argue that this could have better performance than a `cross join`.  Perhaps I shouldn't read the question so literally...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying, Indeed this is a solution, but would be better if I didn't had to do join three times over.

Comment: @HimanshuMehra . . . Not necessarily.  Hive is pretty efficient with joins.